# casting Integer -> Object and later Object -> Integer

Tags: java, casting

Below is a code snippet out of an AVL-tree implementation. It worked fine back in the days, but now it doesn't work any longer. The cause seems to be casting Object to Integer.

So the Avl structure handles Object as data, and the user (in this case main() ) does the casting. What I wanted to achieve was a generic AVL-tree with comparable objects. Actually I insert Objects alongside with a key to be able to distinguish what to sort for. They are internally put in a local class called KeyData.

Here is the code:

```
  // private stuff above - not interesting for problem

  // Public AVL tree methods

  public void insert(Object thedata, String thekey) {
    internal_insert(new KeyData(thedata, thekey));
  }

  public Object find(String key) {
    Object ret = null;
    KeyData x = new KeyData(null, key);
    if(data != null) {
      if(x.compareTo(data) == 0)
    ret = data;
      else if(x.compareTo(data) < 0) {
    if(left != null)
      ret = left.find(key);
      } else {
    if(right != null)
      ret = right.find(key);
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }

  public Object[] inorder() {
    Vector<Object> v = new Vector<Object>();
    iinorder(v);
    return v.toArray();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Avl test = new Avl();
    test.insert(Integer.valueOf(1090), "1");
    test.insert(Integer.valueOf(343452), "2");
    test.insert(Integer.valueOf(3345), "3");
    //Object t2 = test.find("2");
    Object lookfor = test.find("2");
    Integer t2 = (Integer) lookfor; // Line 164
    System.out.println("Got: " + t2.toString());
  }
```

The outcome is like follows:

```
$ java Avl
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    class Avl$KeyData cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (Avl$KeyData is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Integer is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at Avl.main(Avl.java:164)
```

...so what's the story?

Comment: What is `data` in method find? You seem to be using it and comparing it and even returning it but you don't show the part where you initialize it.

Comment: What ever it is, point is that this is where it goes wrong. At some point you assign an object of type `KeyData` to variable `data`. And in your `find` method you are returning whatever variable `data` contains. In main you try to cast it to integer. And obviously you can't cast KeyData to an integer. So maybe you should return something like `KeyData.getData()` instead?

Comment: You  could make KeyData generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...so what's the story?

The short version is that your `find` method doesn't return an `Integer` value.  So you can't *cast* it to an `Integer`.

> It worked fine back in the days, but now it doesn't work any longer.

Well, you must have changed something significant in your code between then and now.  (Hint: the Java language or its implementations have not changed in ways that would cause this!)

So lets take a look at your `find` method.

```
public Object find(String key) {
    Object ret = null;
    KeyData x = new KeyData(null, key);
    if (data != null) {
        if (x.compareTo(data) == 0)
            ret = data;
        else if (x.compareTo(data) < 0) {
            if (left != null)
                ret = left.find(key);
        } else {
            if (right != null)
                ret = right.find(key);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

First observation is that the original indentation of your method was a mess.  Bad indentation makes you code hard for everyone to read ... and understand.  I have fixed it.

So the `find` method is recursively searches a tree, and when it finds a match.  It returns whatever `data` is.  I can't see the declaration of the `Data` field, but the *evidence* is that it is an instance of `Avl.KeyData`.  (Which makes sense ... because you compare `data` with `x` which is a `KeyData` instance.)

Anyhow, that explains why the result isn't an `Integer`.

You haven't shown us the `KeyData` class, but my guess is that it has a `value` field that is / should be an `Integer`.  That's what you should return.  The contents of the found `KeyData` object's value field.

But the big problem here is your use of `Object`.  As @NomadMaker commented, this should really be a generic type with a type parameter that will be the type of the values in the tree.  Then you don't have to use a type cast in `main` ... and the compiler would have told you that it was incorrect for `find` to return a `KeyData<V>` instead of a `V`.

(There are a few other problems with your implementation ... but this is not a "clinic".)